# How to Create a Constant Reference to an Object?

Tags: c++, pointers, object, reference, unique-ptr

I have a design which includes 3 classes as my data structures. Let's call the classes `A`, `B`, and `C`.

I have to instantiate objects of `A`, `B`, and `C` while parsing my input. Each object of class `C` needs to keep track of the corresponding objects in classes `A` and `B`. My current implementation looks like this:

```
class C {
    private:
        A* a;
        B* b;
    public:
        void setA(A* a);
        void setB(B* b);
}
```

I assign `a` and `b` when I create the objects of `A` and `B` using `new` operator. The problem is that I do not want an object of class `C` to be able to modify `a` and `b`. In fact, I only need to know which `a` and `b` correspond to a specific `c`.

One solution could be to define `a` and `b` as `const` pointers/object references. However, in the case of object references, I need to define them as soon as I declare them. The problem is that I am parsing several files and I cannot assign the proper references to `a` and `b` when I define them. In other words, `a` and `b` are created at different times in my program and may not be available when I create `c`.

Recently, I read that it's better to avoid raw pointers as much as possible and that's why I'm trying to implement this using object references instead of pointers. Actually, this is giving me a hard time to figure out which one to use at different stages of my program.

My questions are as follows:

1) Is it better to use object references instead of pointers in this specific question?

2) While this approach works for pointers, what should I do to assign constant references to `a` and `b` if I prefer to use object references instead of pointers?

3) If I use `unique_ptr` for `a` and `b`, what would be the solution to this problem?

Comment: I see nothing preventing you from performing the parsing of the input files inside the `A` and `B` constructors. Or building them as non `const`, setting them up the way you want them, and then passing them in with `set?`. Do that and you can make them `const` pointers. `unique_ptr` is a great idea. Watch out for the Rule of Three.

Comment: Well you can use `const A *a;` and likewise for B; this means you can change where `a` points but cannot change details of the object it's pointing to .  But your entire approach has larger problems and you must think carefully about the lifetimes of the objects you are pointing to.  Using references would be more difficult as they must be bound on construction, there is no possibility of a "setA" function in that case.  `unique_ptr` is only appropriate when you want `C` to manage the lifetimes of the A and B (not clear from your desc. if that is the case, and if so, you could just use values)

Comment: I made a small mistake. I can implement this using pointers, but not object references. The problem is that the lifetime of objects is not determined by `C`. The lifetime of objects is determined by a fourth class which wraps these objects.

What is a good approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: You could have C store a key which you look up in the object manager as needed; or you could have both C and the object manager handle the objects via `shared_ptr`  (then the objects will live until there are no more shared_ptr references to them).

Comment: If you know who the owner is, I'm make that explicit.  Using shared ownership, where everyone has a shared_ptr to the object gets hard to debug in practice.  However if the wapper owns the object, it can have a std::shared_ptr, and the other users can have std::weak_ptr.  That way if the wrapper releases it, the weak_ptr will make that evident.  That said, since the actual owner is a wrapper, and since C will not outlive the wrapper, this is an instance where having the wrapper have a unique_ptr, and C have raw pointers is safe.

Answer (score 2):

1. It is good modern C++ style to avoid using raw pointers.  See
   Chapter 4 of [Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) for details. 
   However, this doesn't mean you cannot use pointers.  I'd also recommend the reading Effective C++, More Effective C++, and Effective STL.
2. So nomenclature wise, the reference or pointer are both pointing
   to the same object.  Under the covers, you are copying around memory
   addresses of the object in question.

   Now to use a const pointer (or reference) the object itself doesn't
   have to be const.  If the function takes a const type* or const
   type&, the type system will tack on the const for you.

   What I think you want is a const pointer.  Here the item being
   pointed to is const, and not the memory address, so you do not have
   to initialize the parameters on construction.  Issue with the const
   reference is what would you initialize it as?  The const type* can
   be set to nullptr on construction, but a reference doesn't have a
   way to have a null value.  I'd say this is important here because
   you will want to be able t tell if the caller assigned a value to a
   or b.  If they didn't, and you properly initialized the member
   variables to nullptr, you can test against that to know they weren't
   set.
3. So in this case, the actual memory to be owned by a
   std::unique_ptr<> and you would pass down a reference or pointer to
   the object. In your situation, sending down the address/pointer is
   the only reasonable thing to do.  you'll want to initialize the
   value to nullptr on construction.  Then you'll be able to tell if
   the caller assigned a value, because the pointer is not null.  If
   you wanted to use a const type&, you'd have to set a valid value at
   construction time, and since their is no null&, their is no obvious
   way to do it.

Also, though this wasn't part of your question, I would document who really owns the memory.  One thing I like about using std::unique_ptr<> is that is makes ownership obvious.

Your updated example:

```
class C {
    private:
        const A* a;
        const B* b;
    public:
        void setA(const A* a);
        void setB(const B* b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I do not want an object of class C to be able to modify a and b. In fact, I only need to know which a and b correspond to a specific c.

Use a const pointer:

```
A const* a;
A const* b;
```

Then deference them, and they will be objects.

Use pointers instead of references, as if you have an instance of C in either class A or B, you will get an error. Using pointers avoids that

(1)It does not matter; you should use pointers because it is easier to see when you are passing a reference. For example:

```
function(a); // Not sure if it is a reference
function(&a); // You know it is that actual object
```

(2) Deference the const pointer, and it will make it a const "reference"

Comment: _"Use pointers instead of references, as if you have an instance of C in either class A or B, you will get an error. Using pointers avoids that"_ So does using references.

Comment: _"It does not matter; you should use pointers because it is easier to see when you are passing a reference"_ This used to be the general consensus, but it isn't any more. References are preferred. It is much easier for you and for your compiler to prove correctness of your program when you stick to tight constructs.

Comment: _"Deference the const pointer, and it will make it a const "reference""_ No it won't

Comment: @PreferenceBean Anything more?

Comment: ""It does not matter; you should use pointers because it is easier to see when you are passing a reference" This used to be the general consensus, but it isn't any more. References are preferred. It is much easier for you and for your compiler to prove correctness of your program when you stick to tight constructs" That is completely opinionated; nothing wrong with my personal preference.

Comment: ""Use pointers instead of references, as if you have an instance of C in either class A or B, you will get an error. Using pointers avoids that" So does using references." That is downright incorrect. References require the actual object to be instantiated, therefore leading to the compiler error. Pointers point to that class and do not cause the same problems

Comment: @J​​​​​​​​​​​​​ava: Then you must be trying to say something with that phrase that's completely different from the way I read it (which related to incomplete types and forward declarations). Can you make it clearer?

Comment: I personally have used pointers more than references. Recently, I read that it's better to avoid raw pointers as much as possible and this is giving me a hard time to figure out what to use at different stages of my program. I hope I can get a good explanation in the comments/answers.

Comment: @Java pointers and references are really the same thing. Both require forward declarations of the type. What you use is a matter of preference, but generally speaking, using raw pointers is bad C++11 style. References or std::weak_ptr would be preferable.